# capistrano3: Don't know how to build task 'deploy:create_db'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano

I use capistrano3 to deploy my rails app.

deploy.rb

```
namespace :deploy do
  after "deploy", "deploy:create_db"
  after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
  after "finishing", "deploy:restart"

  task :restart do
    on roles(:web) do
        execute "mkdir -p #{current_path}/tmp"
        execute "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end

  task :create_db do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
    end
  end

end
```

When I run `cap -T`, the error occurred as below:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:create_db'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`cap -T --trace`

```
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'deploy:create_db'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:353:in `[]'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/capistrano-3.3.5/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:12:in `after'
/Users/liuxingqi/Public/Spar/config/deploy.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

Hope someone can help me, Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: There is no task in Capistrano called create_db. This is something you would need to write yourself.

Comment: I have written in deploy.rb.

Comment: Apologies, so you have. Is that definitely in the deploy namespace?

Comment: yes, I have added the task in deploy namespace.

Comment: Try reordering them so that you define the tasks before calling them.

Comment: it works, but `after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"` doesn't run, it is strange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should define tasks first...

Try this:

```
namespace :deploy do

  task :restart do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{current_path}/tmp"
      execute "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end

  task :create_db do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "cd #{current_path}; bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
    end
  end

  after "deploy", "deploy:create_db"
  after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
  after "finishing", "deploy:restart"
end
```